# How to debug why cmake (with make backend) rebuilds source?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gitlab

I have a Gitlab projects with multiple stages. The output artifacts of the cmake based first stage is handed to the next stage by archiving using the `artifacts:` keyword in the gitlab CI yaml configuration.

The next stage pulls those artifacts successfully, including all the *.o and *.so files to run `ctest` (i.e. it's a "test" stage).

However ctest / cmake decides it needs to build everything from scratch. Is there some mechanism in cmake (or the make backend) to show which rules were triggered and why to warrant a rebuild? E.g. were the artifacts out of date compared to the source or what happened?

Answer (score 1):

In currently available versions of GNU make, your best bet is to use either `make --debug=b` (basic debugging) or if that's not enough, `make --debug=v` (more verbose debugging).

Comment: Good idea, I will tweak our CI build scripts to try and get cmake to run like that. Thing is it's triggered from ctest, but maybe I can simply run make before that with the debug output. Should have the same effect, I guess.